# Error adding to a database in a website remake

Tags: sql, asp.net, oop

I am trying to add a item to my database through a class made by me. I have this error
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

I am not sure where I went wrong but here is my code

```
       protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        int filebytes = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] image = new byte[filebytes];
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(image, 0, filebytes);

        string imagepath = "~/Image/" + filename;

        pro.SaveNewProduct(int.Parse(txtID.Text), txtPName.Text, int.Parse(txtPrice.Text), txtDes.Text, imagepath, int.Parse(DDLCatagory.SelectedValue), int.Parse(DDLNPCAA.SelectedValue), DDLproductype.SelectedValue, int.Parse(txtQuant.Text));
    }


        public void SaveNewProduct(int id, string name, int price, string description, string image, int catagory, int popularity, string kindof, int quantity)
    {
        dal.ClearParams();
        dal.AddParam("@ItemID", id);
        dal.AddParam("@Name", name);
        dal.AddParam("@Price", price);
        dal.AddParam("@Descriptions", description);
        dal.AddParam("@Images", image);
        dal.AddParam("@Catagory", catagory);
        dal.AddParam("@Popularity", popularity);
        dal.AddParam("@Type", kindof);
        dal.AddParam("@Quantity", quantity);
        dal.ExecuteProcedure("spSNI");

    }
```

Also I get the error at the pro.savenewproduct.
I have triple checked to see if I made any mistakes in what I typed as parameters and so far nothing seems off.

I am assuming you mean this, also I only typed 20 in the textbox for price to get this error:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div style="float:right; margin-right:300px">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" />
<br />
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPName" runat="server" Text="Product Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPName"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text="Price"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrice"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="lblDes" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDes"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblquant" runat="server" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuant"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLproductype">
    <asp:ListItem>Select Product Type</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Physical Product</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Service Product</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLNPCAA"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLCatagory"></asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="ID of Existing Item"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDListofitems" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnupdateID" runat="server" Text="Update ID of Item" OnClientClick="btnupdateID_Click" OnClick="btnupdateID_Click" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Item Or Update" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

Comment: Just to check your price contains no formatting? No dollar signs or commas? also can you add your aspx page logic for the fields so we can see their types?

Comment: I solved the error and its all fixed now, I left the ID blank for my sql but that didn't work. Its still not working but the reason I made this was solved so I guess that's the end of that.